# Upgradable packages seem to appear from nowhere on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

My Ubuntu 14.04 server has the default settings for fetching updates i.e. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` has following entries:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
```

My understanding is that `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";` means APT will run `apt-get update` once a day.

When I log into the terminal, it prints out messages about updates, so this seem to confirm the fact that APT is updating the local package cache automatically.

```
3 packages can be updated. 3 updates are security updates.  

Last login:
```

So I run `apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade to newest available packages, but then once the update is performed, if I happen to log out and then log back into the server, I get a message saying:

```
Now there are 30 packages to be updated - 25 security.
```

So then typically I run `sudo apt-get update` just to be sure I actually have the most up to date package cache and then run `apt-get dist-upgrade` again. But even after that, I get a similar prompt when I log out and log back in i.e. `There are more packages to be installed`.

So the typical process involved running `sudo apt-get update`, `apt-get dist-upgrade` 3, 4, or 5 times until the prompts saying `There are more packages to be installed` goes away.

Does anyone know why this keeps happening?

Comment: I don't think `apt-get update` is being run once per day. I think if you try the update command before you do your first `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` command you'll see more packages available for upgrade than are being reported at the login prompt. Not sure why you have to run the dist-upgrade up to 5 times though, that really doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Arronical  Im guessing `apt-get update` is being run sometime because the system is aware of new package versions - without me running update command. but it doesn't seem to matter whether or not update is run prior to the upgrade anyway.  For example, I just right now had to reboot after running `dist-upgrade `.  I think that was the second round of `update` then `dist-upgrade` now I have a message telling me there are `25 packages can be updated. 19 updates are security updates.` . I will try another another `update` then `dist-upgrade` again and see what happens.

Comment: Sure enough, after running `apt-get update` then `dist-upgrade` again, now the system is telling me there are still `25 packages can be updated. 19 updates are security updates`. But Im wondering if this time - its simply the message prompt is not getting updated?

Comment: It seems that was it .. running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` this time  apt-get distupgrade command tells me nothing to install.

Comment: Yes I seem to remember this happening when I've done that, I know it's not always necessary, but I tend to do a reboot after a dist-upgrade, especially if the kernel has been updated. I don't think it can utilise the new kernel without rebooting.

Answer (score -2):

`dist-upgrade` is not the option you want to resolve that issue.

Use `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade`.

`dist-upgrade` is meant to upgrade to a higher version of Linux. The two commands look similar but all you need is `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: "apt-get update" is not really needed as it's been already run once per day. I'd rather add "apt-get autoremove" and "apt-get clean" in order to purge packages that are not needed any more and the package cache.

Comment: I know the command `dist-upgrade` *sounds* like it might upgrade you to a new distro - but it doesn't - and it definitely doesnt upgrade the linux kernel.  @Uqbar thats whats confusing to me, I thought because apt-get update is getting run once a day - it should be up to date right? so where do the new packages keep coming from?

Comment: The package repositories get continuously updated accordingly to the specific release policy (LTS get longer support). So, from time to time, when the apt-get update is run, a new updates can be available to installed packages. This is due to normal updates or to security ones. So, in the end, it's not about new packages being installed but rather old ones (already installed) being updated.